# Oracle database using C++

Tags: c++, oracle

I am trying to print everything in the "WAREHOUSE" table. Below is my code.

ISSUE: Only print 3/10 lines.

[image: Supposed to print this]
[image: But prints this]

```
try
{
    env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
    conn = env->createConnection(usr, pass, srv);
    Statement* stmt = conn->createStatement("SELECT * FROM warehouses");
    /*---------------------CODE-------------------------------*/
    
    ResultSet* rs = stmt->executeQuery();

    if (!rs->next())
    {
        cout << "ResultSet is empty." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (rs->next())
        {
            cout << "Warehouse ID: " << rs->getInt(1) << "Warehouse Name: " << rs->getString(2) << "     " << "Location ID: " << rs->getInt(3) << endl;
        }
    }
    /*---------------------CODE-------------------------------*/
    conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    env->terminateConnection(conn);
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
}
```

Comment: The exit code probably tells you something. `-1073741819` is the same as `0xC0000005` meaning Access Violation in MS Windows. With that said I am not sure why you get an Access Violation here..

Comment: @drescherjm I am still learning and according to my notes, this is how we print the entire table. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: I don't know why this code has an Access Violation. I just wanted to teach you how to read the code. I plugged the `-1073741819` in the windows calculator in Programmer mode and saw that the value was `C0000005` in hexadecimal which is a well known windows code.